# Building a ConsoleMe image using Packer

Tags: containers, amazon-ecs, hashicorp-packer

I am trying to build a ConsoleMe image using Packer and I am getting the following error message: Error: Failed to prepare build: "amazon-ebs"  1 error(s) occurred:  * Destination must be specified.

How can I solve it?

Below is the template that I'm using for the build

````
  "builders": [
    {
      "ami_name": "consoleme {{timestamp}}",
      "instance_type": "t2.micro",
      "region": "us-east-1",
      "source_ami_filter": {
        "filters": {
          "name": "ubuntu/images/*ubuntu-focal-20.04-amd64-server-*",
          "root-device-type": "ebs",
          "virtualization-type": "hvm"
        },
        "most_recent": true,
        "owners": ["099720109477"]
      },
      "ssh_username": "ubuntu",
      "type": "amazon-ebs"
    }
  ],
  "provisioners": [
    {
      "inline": ["sleep 30"],
      "type": "shell"
    },
    {
      "inline": [
        "export CONFIG_LOCATION={{user `CONFIG_LOCATION`}}",
        "export CONSOLEME_CONFIG_ENTRYPOINT={{user `CONSOLEME_CONFIG_ENTRYPOINT`}}",
        "sudo mkdir -p /apps/consoleme",
        "sudo chown -R ubuntu /apps/"
      ],
      "type": "shell"
    },
    {
      "destination": "{{user `app_archive`}}",
      "source": "{{user `app_archive`}}",
      "type": "file"
    },
    {
      "inline": [
        "tar -xzf {{user `app_archive`}} -C /apps/consoleme/",
        "sudo cp -R /apps/consoleme/packer/root/* /",
        "rm {{user `app_archive`}}"
      ],
  "variables": {
    "CONFIG_LOCATION": "{{env `CONFIG_LOCATION`}}",
    "CONSOLEME_CONFIG_ENTRYPOINT": "{{env `CONSOLEME_CONFIG_ENTRYPOINT`}}",
    "app_archive": ""
  }
}```
````